# conf php7.1-cgi does not exist in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I recently moved to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and started getting errors using phpmyadmin. The homepage is showing code instead of the login screen. All the solutions I am trying online aren't helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your current installed PHP version and then fix the `conf php7.1-cgi` command with your version.

For example if you have PHP 7.4 the command will be :

```
conf php7.4-cgi
```

Answer (score 1):

On 18.04 LTS, use php7.2 not php7.1. Run the below commands and it should work:

```
$ sudo apt purge libapache2-mod-php7.2 libapache2-mod-php
```

Then

```
$ sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.2 libapache2-mod-php
```

The proceed to run the command:

```
$ sudo a2enconf php7.2-cgi
```

Comment: Its not working.. I got the error - ERROR: Conf php7.2-cgi does not exist!